# OpenShift Pod terminated when DB Connection fails for .NET 6 app

Tags: kubernetes, entity-framework-core, openshift, .net-6.0

I have a new application running in a container in OpenShift. Currently it can't connect to the database because I'm waiting for the SPN and database permissions to be set up, but the strange thing is that when the application tries the container itself crashes and the pod is restarted.

My code is properly catching exceptions, but it seems as though the pod is restarted immediately when the exception is generated. It works correctly, catching the exception and returning an error message, when run locally.

In OpenShift the last line I see in the logs is:

```
Opening connection to database 'MyDB' on server 'MyServer.domain.com'.
```

OC describe pod shows this:

```
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    139
```

I see that exit code 139 may mean a SIGSEV memory access issue, but I'm not doing anything special with memory. It's just a normal EF Core database context...

My Context declaration is:

```cs
var OptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
    .UseSqlServer("Data Source = MyServer.domain.com; Initial Catalog = MyDB; Integrated Security = True; TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
    .LogTo(Console.Out.WriteLine);

var newContext = new MyContext(OptionsBuilder.Options);

//This line (or any line that causes a database connection) causes the error
newContext.Database.CanConnect();
```

What else should I look at?

Comment: Maybe try SQL Server authentication instead of `Integrated Security`?

Comment: Not allowed by my company.

Comment: I'm just suggesting to check that problem is in `Integrated Security` - then you can dig in right direction.

Comment: OK tried that and it tries opening the connection a few hundred times, but doesn't crash the container at least. (Run locally it just tries and fails once, correctly...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is due to a bug in Microsoft's Microsoft.Data.SqlClient library: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1390

It was patched in version Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0 but EF Core 6 is using a much, much earlier version.

The solution for me was to separately pull in the latest version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in the client app.